# Create Objects for Users in ASP that live for a set amount of time

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I want to move away from calling our database every time a user needs something on the site. It was a good implementation for a few users when we started.

#### Disclaimer: My verbiage is very vague, because I cannot give any vital business information away, I apologize.

Our issue is that we are linking user data via filters and joins and what not depending on zipcodes, and other user information that was filled out. These queries are taking a long time to complete, and they are being called whenever a user visits their dashboard, or visits one of our pages that specifically loads this information. I want to create objects now that holds this data. I would create a Model similar to MVC, but we are not running MVC. We are running basic ASP.NET.

My scenario is that I will create an object for a user when they login.
Process:

1. User Logs in
2. Object is created by system if not in memory
3. As object is constructed, it calls the database for all of the relevant information (userID, First Name, Last Name, Contact Info, Event Info)

I want to create objects in main scope so that when the user logs out the object won't die. I would also like to create a timer object in each instance of these user classes so that they will "die" when I want them to.

I am sorry I did not post any code, but if you need me to, please ask.

I hope someone can shed some light on this.

Comment: ASP.NET supports caching.  It can be implemented at the user level or at the application level.  It can be utilized with expiration dates.

Comment: Actually, this sounds like pretty much the default use case for `Session`. Assuming "die when I want them to" is a reasonable value like "in an hour", rather than, say, "in three months".

Comment: Then how would I relate these objects to a user's session variable? (We have that in place for our logins)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe Application State could be your solution.
Please refer to Microsoft site:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/94xkskdf(v=vs.140).aspx

Best regards

Comment: I will mark this as an answer, because it looks very promising. Thank you :)